# Convert column data from text file into nested lists in Python?

Tags: python, type-conversion, nested-lists, named-entity-recognition

I have a `txt` file with column wise written sentences and labels that look like:

```
O   are
O   there
O   any
O   good
B-GENRE romantic
I-GENRE comedies
O   out
B-YEAR  right
I-YEAR  now

O   show
O   me
O   a
O   movie
O   about
B-PLOT  cars
I-PLOT  that
I-PLOT  talk
```

I want to read data from this `txt` file into two nested lists.
The desired output should be like:

```
labels = [['O','O','O','O','B-GENRE','I-GENRE','O','B-YEAR','I-YEAR'],['O','O','O','O','O','B-PLOT','I-PLOT','I-PLOT']]
sentences = [['are','there','any','good','romantic','comedies','out','right','now'],['show','me','a','movie','about','cars','that','talk']]
```

I have tried with the following:

```
with open("engtrain.bio.txt", "r") as f:
  lsta = []
  for line in f:
    lsta.append([x for x in line.replace("\n", "").split()])
```

But I have the following output:

```
[['O', 'are'],
 ['O', 'there'],
 ['O', 'any'],
 ['O', 'good'],
 ['B-GENRE', 'romantic'],
 ['I-GENRE', 'comedies'],
 ['O', 'out'],
 ['B-YEAR', 'right'],
 ['I-YEAR', 'now'],
 [],
 ['O', 'show'],
 ['O', 'me'],
 ['O', 'a'],
 ['O', 'movie'],
 ['O', 'about'],
 ['B-PLOT', 'cars'],
 ['I-PLOT', 'that'],
 ['I-PLOT', 'talk']]
```

**Update**
I also tried the following:

```
with open("engtest.bio.txt", "r") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  labels = []
  sentences = []
  for l in lines:
    as_list = l.split("\t")
    labels.append(as_list[0])
    sentences.append(as_list[1].replace("\n", ""))
```

Unfortunately, still have an error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-63c266df6ace> in <module>()
      6     as_list = l.strip().split("\t")
      7     labels.append(as_list[0])
----> 8     sentences.append(as_list[1].replace("\n", ""))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

The original data are from this link (engtest.bio or entrain.bio): https://groups.csail.mit.edu/sls/downloads/movie/

Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over each line and split it by `tab`:

```
labels = [[]]
sentences = [[]]
with open('engtrain.bio', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line:
            label, sentence = line.split('\t')
            labels[-1].append(label)
            sentences[-1].append(sentence)
        else:
            labels.append([])
            sentences.append([])
```

Output `labels`:

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'B-ACTOR', 'I-ACTOR'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-ACTOR', 'I-ACTOR', 'O', 'O', 'B-YEAR'] ...
```

Output `sentences`:

```
[['what', 'movies', 'star', 'bruce', 'willis'], ['show', 'me', 'films', 'with', 'drew', 'barrymore', 'from', 'the', '1980s'] ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a little question: how could you download the file with as .bio? I made it using copy-paste to ``txt`` file because the structure by direct downloading was incorrect

Comment: Wow! You did in 12 lines what I did in 25, I'm upvoting :-)

Comment: @AliF Click `Save as` in browser and then select `All file types` option

Answer (score 2):

The lines in your file can be logically grouped into sections, separated by
blank lines. So you have in fact a two-level data structure, you need to
process a list of sections, and inside each section you need to process a list
of lines. Of course, the text file is a flat list of lines, so we need to
re-construct the 2 levels.

This a very general pattern, so here's one way to code this that can be *reused*, regardless of what you need to do inside each section:

```
labels = []
sentences = []

# Prepare next section
inner_labels = []
inner_sentences = []

with open('engtrain.bio.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if len(line.strip()) == 0:
            # Finish previous section
            labels.append(inner_labels)
            sentences.append(inner_sentences)
            # Prepare next section
            inner_labels = []
            inner_sentences = []
            continue
        # Process line in section
        l, s = line.strip().split()
        inner_labels.append(l)
        inner_sentences.append(s)

# Finish previous section
labels.append(inner_labels)
sentences.append(inner_sentences)
```

To reuse this in a different situation, just re-define "Prepare next section", "Process line in section", and "Finish previous section".

There may be a more pythonic way to pre-process the list of lines, etc, but this is a reliable pattern that gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

```
all_labels, all_sentences = [], []
with open('inp', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines.append('') # make sure we process the last sentence
    labels, sentences = [], []
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: # detect the end of a sentence
            if len(labels): # make sure we got some words here
                all_labels.append(labels)
                all_sentences.append(sentences)
                labels, sentences = [], []
            continue
        # extend the current sentence
        label, sentence = line.split()
        labels.append(label)
        sentences.append(sentence)

print(all_labels)
print(all_sentences)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but by applying this code on the original dataset I have the following error: ``IndexError: list index out of range``. I think the problem is because the empty lines between sentences?

Comment: I did this ``words_2d = [ line.split() for line in lines if line !='\n' ]`` it works with empty lines. However it returns two flatten lists. I need the sentences in nested lists :(

Comment: got you, I missed the part about using an empty line to represent the end of a sentence. check out the updated code.